# Throwing errors in API gateway Lambda Authoriser

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-lambda-authoriser

I am writing a custom lambda authoriser used for a V2 HTTP APIGateway.

The authoriser is using the V2 Simple response format.

I have various checks i.e. check a header exists, validate the token, check for custom claims etc.

If any of these fails I have been throwing an error, catching the error in the handlers try/catch so I can log it and then returning `{ isAuthorised: false }` in the catch block.

I expect to get a 401 or 403 in these scenarios however I always receive a HTTP 500 error along with `Internal server error`.

In the lambda logs I can see that my error has been thrown however the unauthorised response is never returned.

In these scenarios I do not want a 500 error, I throw a custom message so this can be used in internal logging.

Below is a cut down example of what my authoriser looks like.

The verifyToken function will throw an error if the token is not valid.

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        if (!event.headers["test-header"]) {
            throw new Error("Missing header")
        }

        const verifiedToken = await verifyToken("access token");

        return { isAuthorised: true }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message ?? "Something went wrong")

        return { isAuthorised: false }
    }
}
```